# Number of dates between two dates

Tags: python, date, datetime

I would like to get the number of days between two dates. But the days does not have to be full 24-hour days. If the first date is right before midnight and the second date is right after midnight, I still want it to count as one day.

```
from datetime import datetime
a = datetime.strptime("2021-07-13 22:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
b = datetime.strptime("2021-07-14 06:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

print((b-a).days)

# Output: 0
# Expected output: 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove the time component of the `datetime` by calling `.date()`,

```py
from datetime import datetime
a = datetime.strptime("2021-07-13 22:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date()
b = datetime.strptime("2021-07-14 06:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date()

print((b-a).days)
```

Comment: So it would be `(b.date()-a.date()).days` in the original code in the question

Comment: @CedricZoppolo sure if you want `a` and `b` to remain as `datetime` objects instead of `date` objects, you could do that.